# How to divide the echo database in pages

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

i have here a code that uses echo to display the contents of my table in a database. my problem is i dont know any method to display it in page because it displays all the data.  here is my current php code

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" class="tablecontainer">
<tr>
<td class="table_titles">ID</td>
<td class="table_titles">Date and Time</td>
<td class="table_titles">Frequency</td>
<td class="table_titles">Wave Height</td>
<td class="table_titles">Longitude</td>
<td class="table_titles">Latitude</td>
</tr>
<?php
include('connection.php');
$result = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY id DESC');

$oddrow = true;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
if ($oddrow)
{
$css_class=' class="table_cells_odd"';
}
else
{
$css_class=' class="table_cells_even"';
}
$oddrow = !$oddrow; 
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td '.$css_class.'>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td '.$css_class.'>" . $row['date_time'] . "</td>";
echo "<td '.$css_class.'>" . $row['height'] . "</td>";
echo "<td '.$css_class.'>" . $row['frequency'] . "</td>";
echo "<td '.$css_class.'>" . $row['latitude'] . "</td>";
echo "<td '.$css_class.'>" . $row['longitude'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>"; 
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
       <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" class="tablecontainer">
    <tr>
    <td class="table_titles">ID</td>
    <td class="table_titles">Date and Time</td>
    <td class="table_titles">Frequency</td>
    <td class="table_titles">Wave Height</td>
    <td class="table_titles">Longitude</td>
    <td class="table_titles">Latitude</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    include('connection.php');
$page = ($_REQUEST[page])?$_REQUEST[page]:1;
$recordperpage=5;
$start = ($_REQUEST[page]-1) * $recordperpage;
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT {$start}, {$recordperpage}");

    $oddrow = true;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    if ($oddrow)
    {
    $css_class=' class="table_cells_odd"';
    }
    else
    {
    $css_class=' class="table_cells_even"';
    }
    $oddrow = !$oddrow; 
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td '.$css_class.'>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td '.$css_class.'>" . $row['date_time'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td '.$css_class.'>" . $row['height'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td '.$css_class.'>" . $row['frequency'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td '.$css_class.'>" . $row['latitude'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td '.$css_class.'>" . $row['longitude'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>"; 
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>

<a href="yourfile.php?page=1">Page 1</a>
<a href="yourfile.php?page=2">Page 2</a>
```

You need to replace yourfile.php to your actual file

Comment: if the answer is helpful, please select as answered.

Comment: i have one more question, what if the database is continuously adding rows.. how will i display it all with pages? because in your method, i have to manually limit the display over and over again while the rows are added

Comment: is there a way that i can display 20 rows per page ?

Comment: change $recordperpage = 20;

Comment: well, you have to count the total row of records using COUNT, and use ceil to calculate the page number. but that's out of scope.

Comment: you are suppose the select an answer, please do so.

Comment: i have less than 15 reputation so i cant up your answer im sorry